# Equilibrium positions of a tilted rod rotating around vertical axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators, equilibrium

First of all, this is my first ever question on any forum so forgive me if it's not so well written. Second, I'm not a native English speaker so if there is any writing error, I'm sorry.

[image: Image of the problem]

> The problem is as follows: the rod of mass $m$ is fixed at point $A$ and it rotates around axis $e$ with an angular velocity $\Omega$. Nothing is said about the angle $\theta$, so I assume it's constant.
>
> The problem asks to determine, in terms of $\Omega$, the equilibrium positions and their stability. The solutions appear to be:

- $\theta = 0$, stable if $\Omega^2 < \frac{3g}{2l}$
- $θ = \mathrm{acos}\left(\frac{3g}{2lΩ^2}\right)$, stable if $\Omega^2 > \frac{3g}{2l}$

The problem is I don't really know where to even start.
It's the first time I take Mechanics lessons (2nd year university) and my professor has been horrible to say the least, so if it seems a trivial problem for some of you, please bear with me.

I hope that someone can give me an explanation on how to get to those solutions.

Comment: This problem can be easilily solved using Lagrangian mechanics otherwise it is a bit awkward...However it is a good starting point to work in the rotating non-inertial reference system...

Comment: Yes. I see that there's a newtonian-mechanics tag, newbie mistake there, I'll remove it. Many other exercises that I have done about this are using Lagrangian mechanics, so anyway, could you please elaborate on how to solve it with Lagrangian mechanics? Thanks

Comment: Use $\theta$ as Lagrangian coordinate and use the potential energy which includes both the gravitational energy end the centrifugal energy.

Answer (score 0):

You start the same always.

1. Identify the degrees of freedom,
2. establish the acceleration kinematics in terms of the degrees of freedom and their derivatives,
3. draw a free body diagram,
4. formulate the equations of motion (sum of forces and torques) at each center of mass.
5. Check that you have $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns, otherwise you are missing some additional equations (like friction, or actuator forces).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the free body diagram for a mathematical pendulum

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\text{centrifugal force}}{\text{weight}}=f(\Omega~,\Theta~,L)$$

for physical pendulum

$$L\mapsto \frac{I}{L/2}$$

- $I~$ Inertia of the rod about the center of mass
- $L~$ pendulum length
- $m~$ pedulum mass